# Create a global svelte-component that works like svelte:head

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, svelte-component

In my current project I am working with a self-developed module system, where the individual modules should also have the possibility to extend  e.g.the navbar by simply writing some HTML inside a `<navbar:extend>` tag.

It would be cool if there was a way to get it done with as little writing as the `<svelte:head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a store to which you will write (update with) your HTML extensions from your Components and at the same time subscribe to that store within your NavComponent then within NavComponets append the new HTML using [{@html variable}](https://svelte.dev/docs#html)

like that you can append HTML from different components to your Navbar, this should achieve the functionality you desire.

[here is a quick example of the implementation](https://svelte.dev/repl/12b2fdf1775240e9a1f0b754c3062c61)

`Child1.svelte` and `Child2.svelte` are two random components which are going to update you navbar.

`Store.svelte` is the file where you will create your global store to share HTML.

`Nav.svelte` is the navbar you want to populate with HTML from other components

try writing some HTML within Child1 and Child2 input fields then submit it, it will be rendered within the NavComponent